# Split filename and get integer value from filename in python 2.7

Tags: python-2.7

File name "Track_File_1520speed_vs_angle". I want to get just 1520 from file name and assign to variable.

```
rpmMatch=re.search(r'(Track_File_)([0-9]+)(speed_vs_angle)',filename, x, y, z, f)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use negative lookahead to find text without selecting it. To grab any digits after `Track_File_` you could use `(?!Track_File_)[0-9]+` as your regex. This will match `1520`.